# Convert PDF to HTML by Javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

Is there any way to convert PDF to HTML that can be edited？When a user uploads a PDF file, it can be converted into HTML, and some contents in it can be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Not without a third party library. Most likely you will have to save the PDF to the server, run the third party library against it, render the HTML.